# Is there any font like this?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

I want to use this font.

- What is it?
- Are the birds part of the font? Or are they an effect?
- If it's effect, How I can get this effect? Is it included into some common easily available software?

Comment: So how can I this type of font manipulation? Is there a software or I website where I can ask someone to create me words with this type of font manipulation style?

Answer (score 0):

The basic font is Soolidium. See it: http://www.dafont.com/soolidium.font

The blackbird disintegration or accumulation effect is someone's custom creation.

Your image exists in some websites, for example in pinterest. I am not their customer so I cannot see, if there is some info about how to get the effect.

You find those websites by searching "Blackbird font manipulation" That is in your image.